# HostListener works to ngModel, but not to FormControl

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have this directive that make use of hostlistener to listen ngModelChange to control input text. I intend to use the same directive to control text typed on a FormGroup/FormControl input.

Directive

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][appPureName]'
})
export class PureNameDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) {}

  @HostListener('ngModelChange')
  onModelChange() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.value) {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
    }
  }

}
```

I would like to use the save directive, with another Hostlistener to control the text as I do to ngModel input.

I have tried to implement the above example, but it does not works.

```
 @HostListener('input',['$event']) onEvent($event){
    let valueToTransform = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    // do something with the valueToTransform
    this.control.control.setValue(valueToTransform);
  }
```

The real question is: Can I use `HostListener` with `formControlName`? If so, can I control/change the value from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, since `HostListener` listen to `DOM Events` and values passed/changed through `setValue` or `patchValue` doesn't trigger any type of DOM event, hence they will not pass through your `Directive` logic.

In my case I chose to use either the directive and manually creating the `Mask` inside the component, so it's possible to keep listen to `input` events when they occur and also be able to apply the `Mask` when using `setValue` or `patchValue`.